# Higher impact factor vs. more focused journal

Tags: publications

I am going to publish a paper and I narrowed my alternatives down to two:

1. the first journal has impact factor 9.2, but it has a broader audience, in terms of research topics.
2. the second one has impact factor 3.8 but it is more focused and more familiar to my research community. The paper may be seen more easily by people that work in my field.

The paper would be in the scope of both the journals, which alternative would you pick?

Comment: Depends on the type of papers you are writing.  That is, you need to consider the audience of your paper; writing for a general audience is very different to a specialize audience.  In my area, general journals (so called magazines) have minimal equations for example.  Also, they are more focused on getting concepts across as opposed to being bogged down by formalism; they tend to be introductory in nature.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Both the journals are focused on the formalism, none of them is a ‘‘magazine’’. The broader journal covers many aspects of mechanical and material engineering (equations of state, mechanical response models, chemical behavior and/or magnetic properties of materials, multiphase/multimaterial transport phenomena, and respective practical applications). The second journal is more focused on chemistry and transport processes (which is also the topic of my paper). My paper would fit in the focused journal and be in the scope of the broader one,but together with other topics.

Comment: Both journals have a strongly mathematical layout.

Comment: then my suggestion is simply to select one arbitrarily.  If the paper is good, it will be read if it appears in a reputable venue.

Comment: My other suggestion is probably update your question to name the journals in question.  Someone in your area may provide more specific answers; e.g., the review process, or expectations of the communities that read one or both journals.

Comment: The first journal, high impact -> more reads + broader audience -> citations